# Отметил сообщение тревогой — как отозвать пометку?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Отметил ответ тревогой (как низкого качества). Сейчас [этот ответ заминусован](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/292394/181472) и вполне вероятно, что будет удален.

За полчаса, пока прочитал документацию по вопросу, понял, как можно просто улучшить. А как теперь отменить тревогу?

Пока что я удалил вредоносную часть и сменил свой голос с «против» на «воздержался».

---

[Похоже, что это невозможно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/296059). В таком случае, что мне сделать, чтобы минимизировать вред? Давайте отвлечемся от данного ответа и рассмотрим вопрос «вообще». Что если я поставил отметку тревоги, а затем

- Обнаружил, что поставил отметку не на то сообщение, которое хотел отметить
- Сообщение было отредактировано, улучшено и более не заслуживает отметки тревоги
- Я могу самостоятельно улучшить сообщение так, чтобы оно не заслуживало отметки тревоги
- Оказывается, я неверно понимаю смысл сообщения. Отметка не нужна

Могу ли я своей отметкой нанести вред полезному сообщению (например, это приведет к удалению или голосам «против»)? Как мне минимизировать потенциальный вред?

Comment: В ответах прошу ориентироваться не на меня лично, а на медианного пользователя SO, то есть новичка с 1 репутации, который не подозревает об очередях проверки и прочем.

Comment: Видимо *очень хорошо думать*, прежде чем совершать потенциально разрушительные (или просто обидные для автора) действия.

Comment: Мне кажется, для всех кейсов ответ: *Модератор увидит и снимет флаг*.

Comment: Правда минусы от этого не аннигилируют.

Comment: @Nofate: за отметку «низкого качества» Дух минусов не ставит же. Только за спам и оскорбления.

Comment: Так люди ставят.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ с учетом того, что я узнал о работе тревог, будучи модератором:

Тревоги типов «необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством» и «не является ответом» обрабатываются сразу в двух местах:

- В соответствующих очередях проверок, всеми пользователями.
- В модераторской очереди.

Соответственно, тревога снимается в любом из этих случаев:

- Достаточно голосов из очереди проверок (хоть подтверждающих, хоть опровергающих тревогу).
- Вопрос или ответ удалён.
- Тревога вручную снята модератором.

Поэтому если тревога поставлена ошибочно и вы хотите минимизировать ущерб — можно отправить «вдогонку» ещё одну тревогу типа «требует внимания модератора». Обе тревоги будут видны модератору одновременно и вместе. Разумеется, пока модератор не отреагирует, сообщение не уйдет из очереди проверок. После снятия тревоги должно уйти.

Второй путь — написать комментарий для проверяющих. Что-то вроде «Ошибочно отметил тревогой, на самом деле с сообщением всё хорошо».

Comment: но есть же возможность самостоятельно отозвать тревогу на сообщении, если нажать кнопку "отозвать" в меню выбора варианта тревоги

Comment: @mymedia вроде раньше не было такого пункта меню.